# What's the difference between LibreOffice multi and all_lang packages?

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, i18n

There seem to be 2 different multi-language LibreOffice distributions available for Win32 platform:

- LibO_3.3.1_Win_x86_install_multi.exe (213 MB)
- LibO_3.3.1_Win_x86_install_all_lang.exe (248 MB)

What's the difference between them other than 35 MBs of size and the names themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See their [help page](http://www.libreoffice.org/index.php/get-help/faq/general-faq/why-is-the-windows-installer-so-big/) - it's down to how many languages you need.

Answer (score 1):

When you download LibreOffice for Windows, you get the choice between two downloads: one is about 215 Megabytes in size and the other is about 253 Megabytes. The smaller download includes a selection of the most-commonly chosen languages, while the larger download includes every language currently supported by LibreOffice. However, both installers give you exactly the same features in terms of the functionality you get in the installed software.